# How to stop a blocked handler thread?

Tags: android, aidl, android-handlerthread

I have bind an activity to a remote service through aidl interface. Various other activities are also bound to it. After some point of time, calls are getting blocked. When I open that particular activity it starts a handlerthread and it is calling some remote methods through aidl interface. But they are blocked so thread is also getting blocked. Inside onDestroy() method, I am trying to do handlerthread.quit(), but thread is not stopping. So every time I am starting that activity threads are started but not getting stopped on destroying activity.

My question is how can I stop the handlerthread which is in blocked state?

Comment: Your aidl interface needs to have 'oneway' nonblocking methods calls that return straight away - in your constructor for your 'oneway' method call define a 'callback' to your handler.

Comment: did you  tried thread.interrupt() ?

Comment: @user3549047 i tried interrupt. But thread was not stopped.

Comment: It seems it got blocked in 'onTransact' waiting for the remote binder thread to respond.

Answer (score 0):

your aidl interfaces might be bidirectional.
try making them `oneway` which will make them non-blocking.

Also, if your requirement is not to make them onway, check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14932332/should-i-manually-close-handlerthreads-created-by-my-application-when-destroying) there it explains how to stop a handler thread.

Comment: I tried this. mBTHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
  mBTHandler = null;
  BTWorkerThread.quit();
  if(BTWorkerThread.isAlive())
   BTWorkerThread.interrupt();
  BTWorkerThread = null; But it didnot work.