# CountDown Timer on activity start

Tags: java, android, countdown

how to manage a countdown to begin right away with an activity start and to start new activity when time is up? Thanks in advance

Edits:
Activity contatins a button. User should press it until time is up, otherwise another activity starts

Comment: I don't understand these kind of questions ... to me it seems you have described the solution from the question

Comment: are you talking about Splash Screen ?

Comment: @user3291365, not a Splach Screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this in two ways

**METHOD 1:** Creation of  a thread and setting time to sleep exactly after that redirection to main app screen.
**METHOD 2:** Set time to handler and call Handler().postDelayed , it will surly call run method of runnable after setting the time and redirection to main app screen.

we can implement in this given way wher we can write code for our MainScreen

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainScreen extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainscreen);

// METHOD 1     

         /****** Create Thread that will sleep for 10 seconds *************/        
        Thread background = new Thread() {
            public void run() {

                try {
                    // Thread will sleep for 10 seconds
                    sleep(10*1000);

                    // After 10 seconds redirect to another intent
                    Intent i=new Intent(getBaseContext(),AnotherScreen .class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    //Remove activity
                    finish();

                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
        };

        // start thread
        background.start();

//METHOD 2  

        /*
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            // Using handler with postDelayed called runnable run method

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainScreen.this, AnotherScreen.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // close this activity
                finish();
            }
        }, 10*1000); // wait for 10 seconds
        */
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();

    }}
```

the AnotherScreen  code can be as follows

```
    import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class AnotherScreen extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.anotherScreen); 

    } 

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();

    }
}
```

for an another example visit http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/how-to-implement-android-splash-screen-2/

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/31295/review-request-android-countdowntimer-activity

Comment: Cool solution, very easy! But is there any way to display a timer(connected with the thread) on the screen?

Comment: yes do something in such a way that you can update some widget or textview, it depends on yours implementation!!

Comment: Is there any way to stop or interupt Handler from Method 2 if I moved to another activity with a special button? I have added a button which starts another activity, if it is not clicked then handler do that, but if i used button, then handler continues to work, how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: yes do something like this handler.removeMessages(what); or mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(HandleUpdateInd.class); please visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038038/how-to-stop-the-handler

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
        //start new activity
     }
  }.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer you are looking for a **spalshActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
    try {
        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,
                        MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();

            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 300);// DElay of 300 mil sec
    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e("ERROR in Splash Screen", e.toString());
    }

}
```